# ATSAM4S2A PLL not locking or unlocking

Tags: c, arm, embedded, atmel

I am using the Atmel ATSAM4S2A with a 11 MHz crystal connected. I want to use the PLL to make a 110MHz MCK. The crystal clock is output on PCK0 and is ok. The PLL sometimes locks, but immediately unlocks again.

The clock init code:

```
void Init_Clock(void) {

    REG_PMC_WPMR = PMC_WPMR_WPKEY_PASSWD;

    // Set Flash WaitStates
    REG_EFC0_FMR |= (EEFC_FMR_FWS(5) | EEFC_FMR_CLOE);

    // Enable Crystal Oscillator
    PMC->CKGR_MOR = CKGR_MOR_KEY_PASSWD | 
                    CKGR_MOR_MOSCXTST(0xFFul) | 
                    CKGR_MOR_MOSCRCEN | 
                    CKGR_MOR_MOSCXTEN;

    while (!(REG_PMC_SR & PMC_SR_MOSCXTS));
    
    //Select Crystal for Main Clock
    PMC->CKGR_MOR = CKGR_MOR_KEY_PASSWD | 
                    CKGR_MOR_MOSCXTST(0xfful) | 
                    CKGR_MOR_MOSCRCEN | 
                    CKGR_MOR_MOSCXTEN | 
                    CKGR_MOR_MOSCSEL;

    while (!(REG_PMC_SR & PMC_SR_MOSCSELS));
    
    //Write PLL Value (11.2896MHz * 10/1 = 112.896MHz)
    PMC->CKGR_PLLAR = CKGR_PLLAR_ONE | 
                      ( CKGR_PLLAR_MULA(0x9ul) | 
                        CKGR_PLLAR_DIVA(1ul) | 
                        CKGR_PLLAR_PLLACOUNT(0x3ful) );

    while (!(REG_PMC_SR & PMC_SR_LOCKA));
        
    PMC->PMC_MCKR = PMC_MCKR_PRES_CLK_1 | 
                    PMC_MCKR_CSS_PLLA_CLK;

    while (!(REG_PMC_SR & PMC_SR_MCKRDY));

    // Select Main Clock for PCK0:
    REG_PMC_PCK = PMC_PCK_CSS_MAIN_CLK;
    
    // Enable Clock Output on PCK0
    REG_PMC_SCER |= (1 << 8);
}
```

VDDPLL is connected to VDDOUT. I tried to decouple the VDDPLL input according to the AT03463 checklist, but it made no difference. Currently I just have one 100nF on the VDDPLL pin.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Does it require an external PLL filter? Hardware-related/borderline hardware questions are better asked at https://electronics.stackexchange.com btw.

Comment: Check out a reference design.  For example https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tool/ATSAM4S-XPRO.  The schematic for that has a 12MHz crystal and a note explaining how to calculate the crystal load capacitors.  It too has 100nF on VDDPLL.  If all that is correct _then_ it may be a software problem, but by casting doubt on your hardware design, it is perhaps not a given yet?

Comment: The schematic also has a note about a missing LC filter on VDDPLL, but states that may be a problem for the 48MHz PLL (for USB), and refers you to [AT03463](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/Atmel-42155-SAM4S-Schematic-Checklist_ApplicationNote_AT03463.pdf) - (which contrary to the note has an RLC filter).  It includes advice on the crystal circuit and other aspects of schematic design too.

Comment: Yes I have read the two documents. Also I decided to put the LC filter (as recommended in AT03463) back in. It makes no difference. Crystal clock is stable.